# "Compress" an AIFF file?

Tags: audio, mp3, compression, audacity

I'm wondering how I can compress several AIFF files to reduce their size

at this point I don't care about sound quality, I just need to reduce the file size

the problem is that AIFF is an uncompressed file size, and I can't change the rate from 16 bit to 8 bit (it needs to be 16 bits AIFF)

Is there a way to do that ?

I'm not familiar with how AIFF and other files formats really worked but I noticed that even when I compress the file to a poor quality MP3 file, re-import the MP3 and then export back to AIFF I get the same file size

so is the AIFF file size only dependent on the length of each track ?

I'm using Audacity but I'm willing to download any other software if there is a solution

thanks

Comment: Why are you wanting to do this? What's the reason

Comment: FLAC (free) and ALAC (Apple) could reduce file size of about 40% with absolutely no loss of quality. OGG (free), MP3 (licensed) and AAC (Apple) would provide a reduction file size by a factor of 4 times to maybe 20 times depending on the quality loss you can accept.

Answer (score 1):

Uncompressed audio is a direct stream from the source, there's no loss in quality. Because of this, there's virtually no way to lower the file size of uncompressed because it **is** dependent on audio length. Your best bet would be to settle for a lower-quality MP3.

Keep in mind that MP3's are just as universal as uncompressed when it comes to compatibility. You're unlikely to run across hardware or software that doesn't support either one.